# r RCurl postForm() loop through a vector or data frame into a text field form

Tags: html, r, post, rcurl

The goal is to pass each observation on the variable "finput" into a HTML form where the variable is called "text".  I have no issues if I do a single observation.

So, I am trying to use RCurl postForm() and I am struggling since for some reason it is not looping through the vector or a dataframe that I called "finput" (I’ve tested both methods).

Here is my vector code snapshot

```
for (i in 1:length(finput)){
    ...
    fget[i] <- postForm("http://localhost:80/", text = finput, button = "Go", httpheader=c('Host'="localhost:80"), .opts = list(header = TRUE, verbose = TRUE), style="post")[i]
    ...
}
```

Here is what is on the vector

```
str(finput)
chr [1:3] "Text blah blah blah..." | __truncated__ ...
```

Code output of "fget"

```
fget
[1] "{\"id\":\"*UNKNOWN*\",\"source\":\"*UNKNOWN*\",\..."
[2] NA
[3] NA
```

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing I was able to figure it out.  Apparently one of my vectors was carrying this character -> ’ = E28099 (ASCII = HEX), so when I was running the postForm(), it was bundling all 3 vectors into one (not really sure as of why).  So, I ran the following function `finput <- gsub("’", "'", finput)` to replace that character with a single quote and everything went back to normal.